# How can I use a list-like type to generate a markdown with string.Template python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, markdown

I have the following Template

```
from string import Template
myTemplate = '''$heading
| Name | Age |
| ---- |---- |
'''
```

The problem is that I don't know when writing the template how many people there will be in the table. So I would like to pass in a list of tuples such as:

```
myTemplate.substitute(...=[("Tom", "23"), ("Bill", "43"), ("Tim", "1")])
```

How can this be done? If I just add in a placeholder for the list with tuples, this would not work since the surrounding formatting of the data would be lost.

I would like the template to capture the formatting and the list to capture the data and keep those two elements separate.

The result should be as follows:

```
| Name | Age |
| ---- |---- |
| Tom  | 23  |
| Bill | 43  |
| Tim  | 1   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a reason for not wanting to import a fully featured templating engine, such as wanting to run the code in a seriously resource-limited environment. If so, it's not hard to do this in a few lines of code.

The following can cope with a list of tuples of up to 26 elements itentified as $A to $Z in the template string, and returns a list of template expansions.

```
from string import Template

def iterate_template( template, items):
   AZ=[ 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[i:i+1] for i in range(26) ] # ['A','B',... 'Z']
   return [ Template(template).safe_substitute(
       dict(zip( AZ, elem ))) for elem in items ]
```

Edit: for efficiency I should probably have instantiated the Template once and used it multiple times in the list comprehension:

```
def iterate_template( template, items):
   AZ=[ 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[i:i+1] for i in range(26) ] # ['A','B',... 'Z']
   tem = Template(template)
   return [ tem.safe_substitute( dict(zip( AZ, elem ))) for elem in items ]
```

examples of use

```
>>> table = [('cats','feline'), ('dogs','canine')]

>>> iterate_template('| $A | $B |', table )
['| cats | feline |', '| dogs | canine |']

>>> x=Template('$heading\n$stuff').substitute( 
      heading='This is a title',
      stuff='\n'.join(iterate_template('| $A | $B | $C |', 
         [('cats','feline'),   ('dogs', 'canine', 'pack')] ) ) # slight oops
  )
>>> print(x)
This is a title
| cats | feline | $C |
| dogs | canine | pack |
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache). This is a simple template engine that can do what you need.

Comment: Seems like python does not have anything in-built for this rather than manually doing it therefore a more complete system would be nicer to have.